# Google + Domains API Quick start for java is not working

Tags: java, google-api, google-plus, google-api-java-client, google-authentication

I am trying to use the domains API offered in Google +, I am trying to make work to Quick start for java using domain-wide delegation I have followed the steps, also I have asked my domain admin to grant access to the project I created in console, resuming I can compile the java file, but when I run, I get a 404 error, here is the code:

```
 /*
 * Copyright 2013 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package com.google.plus.samples.quickstart.domains;

import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.plusDomains.PlusDomains;
import com.google.api.services.plusDomains.model.Acl;
import com.google.api.services.plusDomains.model.Activity;
import com.google.api.services.plusDomains.model.PlusDomainsAclentryResource;
import com.google.api.services.plusDomains.model.Person;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;


/**
 * Simple program to demonstrate the Google+ Domains API.
 *
 * This program shows how to authenticate an app for domain-wide delegation and how
 * to complete an activities.insert API call. For details on how to authenticate on
 * a per-user basis using OAuth 2.0, or for examples of other API calls, please see
 * the documentation at https://developers.google.com/+/domains/.
 *
 * @author joannasmith@google.com (Joanna Smith)
 */
public class DomainDelegation {
  /**
   * Update SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL with the email address of the service account for the client ID
   *  created in the developer console.
   */
  private static final String SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = "example@developer.gserviceaccount.com";

  /**
   * Update SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH with the file path to the private key file downloaded
   *  from the developer console.
   */
  private static final String SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH =
      "file-privatekey.p12";

  /**
   * Update USER_EMAIL with the email address of the user within your domain that you would like
   *  to act on behalf of.
   */
  private static final String USER_EMAIL = "example@email.com";


  /**
   * plus.me and plus.stream.write are the scopes required to perform the tasks in this quickstart.
   *  For a full list of available scopes and their uses, please see the documentation.
   */
  private static final List<String> SCOPE = Arrays.asList(
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.stream.write",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.circles.read",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profiles.read",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.stream.read",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile");


  /**
   * Builds and returns a Plus service object authorized with the service accounts
   * that act on behalf of the given user.
   *
   * @return Plus service object that is ready to make requests.
   * @throws GeneralSecurityException if authentication fails.
   * @throws IOException if authentication fails.
   */
  private static PlusDomains authenticate() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {

    System.out.println(String.format("Authenticate the domain for %s", USER_EMAIL));

    HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
    JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

    // Setting the sub field with USER_EMAIL allows you to make API calls using the special keyword 
    // 'me' in place of a user id for that user.
    GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
        .setTransport(httpTransport)
        .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
        .setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
        .setServiceAccountScopes(SCOPE)
        .setServiceAccountUser(USER_EMAIL)
        .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(
            new java.io.File(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH))
        .build();

    System.out.println("credential " + credential);
    // Create and return the Plus service object
    PlusDomains service = new PlusDomains.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential).build();

    return service;
  }

  /**
   * Create a new post on behalf of the user associated with the credential object of the service,
   * restricted to the domain.
   *
   * @param service Plus service object that is ready to make requests.
   * @throws IOException if the insert operation fails or if authentication fails.
   * @throws GeneralSecurityException if authentication fails.
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // Create an authorized API client
    PlusDomains service = authenticate();

    // Set the user's ID to 'me': requires the plus.me scope
    String userId = "me";
    String msg = "Happy Monday! #caseofthemondays";

    System.out.println("Inserting activity " + service);

    // Create the audience of the post
    PlusDomainsAclentryResource res = new PlusDomainsAclentryResource();

    // Share to the domain
    res.setType("domain");


    List<PlusDomainsAclentryResource> aclEntries = new ArrayList<PlusDomainsAclentryResource>();
    aclEntries.add(res);

    Acl acl = new Acl();
    acl.setItems(aclEntries);

    // Required, this does the domain restriction
    acl.setDomainRestricted(true);

    Activity activity = new Activity()
        .setObject(new Activity.PlusDomainsObject().setOriginalContent(msg))
        .setAccess(acl);
    //System.out.println("ativity " + activity);

    activity = service.activities().insert(userId, activity).execute();

    System.out.println(activity);
  }
}
```

Obviusly the data like email and key file I have the correct in my code, this is the error I get:

```
Authenticate the domain for example@email.com
credential com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential@2b275d39
04-dic-2013 8:59:50 com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClient <init>
ADVERTENCIA: Application name is not set. Call Builder#setApplicationName.
Inserting activity com.google.api.services.plusDomains.PlusDomains@46b8c8e6
Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 404 Not Found
Not Found
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:145)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:312)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1045)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:410)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
    at com.google.plus.samples.quickstart.domains.DomainDelegation.main(DomainDelegation.java:154)
```

I am lost, please if somebody could help me I would be grateful.

Comment: Did you create your client ID in the Google Cloud Console or in the older Google APIs Console?

Comment: The link in the Quick Start for Java seems to be the older Google API Console, when I make hover in the link this is the address: http://developer.google.com/console, but I did not clicked the link, I went to the older console, after your comment I clicked in the link and I was taken to other console I had not used, there is a difference?

Comment: I heard of an issue recently with service account credentials from the new console not working correctly. Not sure if that is still the case though.

Comment: Well I will try the other option, did you see my comment in your first response about the service which I used to create the client ID? do you think it could be a problem?

Comment: What is more weird for me is that the response is a 404 error not found, is not a problem of grant access, it looks like something was broken, but I have to use all the suggestions and options.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the line that contains PlusDomains.builder now requires that the setApplicationName be called:

```
PlusDomains service = new PlusDomains.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential)
  .setApplicationName('MyDomainsDemo')
  .build();
```

Comment: I made your suggestion, but still I have the same problem, I have to add something, the service account which I used for generating the client ID, email and private-key file is precisely a service account of my company, so this accunt has not associated a G+ account, then I don't know if this feature could affect, I have also read the FAQ section in the documentantion and mentions about the order of scopes in my java file and in the permissions given by my administrator, it says that it has to be in the same order, I think that is not the reason, but what do you think about what mentioned?

Comment: Accounts do not need to be Google+ accounts to create the credentials. We'll see if we can recreate the problem.

Comment: Thank you, I would be very grateful if youn can help me.

Comment: @JohnB What your log says after trying this solution? Because it should be solved by this.

Comment: @Jhanvi In the results I get the same error, the only part that changes when use setApplicationName is that these two lines disappear:                                                        13-dic-2013 9:25:29 com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClient <init>
ADVERTENCIA: Application name is not set. Call Builder#setApplicationName.                                        But the same error appears, some idea??

Answer (score 0):

I tested the Java sample today and it works. The instructions need a few minor updates related to labels changing in the API console, but if you configure the application correctly, you will be able to get started.

The 404 error is most likely caused by a misconfigured client and is not an issue in the sample. The following screenshot should be helpful in getting the correct credentials. When you create the service account, you will get a new region highlighted below:

[image: Sources for Java Quickstart credentials]

Make sure that the Client ID under **Service Account** is the same client ID added when you performed Domain-Wide delegation from the Admin console. The following screenshot shows where the client ID (the first field in the previous screenshot) goes:

[image]

Finally, make sure that the email address configured in `src/com/google/plus/samples/quickstart/domains/DomainDelegation.java` matches the email from your service account.

If you are using the classic API console, you will need to add a service account to your project, Do this from API Access -> Create another client ID... -> Service account. The values will then come from the added section:

[image]

Comment: Ok, I will try to check all is in place, why in your first screenshot appears Client ID for web application? is no related with the service account? and I have other question, the account I use to create the Service Account it does not matter that is not an administrator account, right? or I have to use an administrator account to create the Service Account

Comment: The account that I tested with was an administrator account, I am not sure whether it is required but that could be your issue. Let me know if changing your account to an administrator helps so I can revise my answer as appropriate.

Comment: In the screenshot that you attached I see you are using the new console of Google for the projects, in my case I got the credential from the old console, do you think it could be making some kind of trouble this feature?

Comment: The classic API console will still work, you just need to create Service Account credentials and use those.

Comment: OK then I assume that in your screenshot the section that says Client ID for web application is not relevant? or there is something I am omitting?

Comment: Correct, the only relevant section for Google Domains API access is the service account.

Comment: Finally I could make it work, I received an advise in G+ of adding setRootUrl("https://www.googleapis.com/") to the PlusDomains.Builder, and magically it worked, is not a matter of the service account, I only added that and worked, do you have idea of why was that missing?

Comment: @JohnB No idea why it was missing, but the sample working after the change may be related to the comment from BrettJ.

Comment: What a weird thing, well at least that pain is over, when you made the example I think you used the code like is in the tutorial, right? without this kind of little modifications.

Answer (score 0):

> this works!
>
> with those jars
>
> antlr-2.7.7.jar                       jackson-core-asl-1.9.11.jar
>   aopalliance-1.0.jar                   javassist-3.15.0-GA.jar
>   commons-email-1.3.2.jar                   jboss-logging-3.1.0.GA.jar
>   commons-logging-1.1.1.jar             jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar
>   dom4j-1.6.1.jar                       jsr305-1.3.9.jar
>   google-api-client-1.17.0-rc.jar               jstl-1.2.jar
>   google-api-client-jackson2-1.17.0-rc-sources.jar  mail-1.4.1.jar
>   google-api-services-calendar-v3-rev87-1.19.0.jar  mysql-connector-java-5.1.22.jar google-collections-1.0-rc2.jar              spring-aop-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar
>   google-http-client-1.17.0-rc.jar          spring-beans-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar
>   google-http-client-jackson-1.17.0-rc.jar      spring-context-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar
>   google-oauth-client-1.17.0-rc.jar         spring-core-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar
>   google-oauth-client-servlet-1.17.0-rc.jar     spring-expression-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar
>   hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.1.Final.jar     spring-jdbc-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar
>   hibernate-core-4.1.10.Final.jar               spring-orm-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar
>   hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar         spring-tx-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar
>   hsqldb-2.2.9.jar                  spring-web-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar
>   httpclient-4.0.1.jar                  spring-webmvc-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar
>   httpcore-4.0.1.jar                    transaction-api-1.1.jar jackson-core-2.1.3.jar

...

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;


import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.DateTime;
import com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar;
import com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Event;
import com.google.api.services.calendar.model.EventAttendee;
import com.google.api.services.calendar.model.EventDateTime;
```

..

```
public class GoogleCalNotificator {
public static void addEvent(TurnosRepository repo, String fecha,
            String inicio, String fin, String paciente, String cliente) {

    HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
    JacksonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
    String scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar";

    GoogleCredential credential = null;
    try {
        credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                .setTransport(httpTransport)
                .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
                .setServiceAccountId(
                        "xxxxxxxxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com")
                .setServiceAccountUser("xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com")
                .setServiceAccountScopes(Arrays.asList(scope))
                .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(
                        new File(repo.getParameter("P12_FILE"))) //p12 from gooleapiuser

                .build();
    } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Calendar service = new Calendar.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory,
            credential).setApplicationName("appname").build();

    // -----------------
    Event event = new Event();

    event.setSummary("text " );
    event.setLocation("loc ");

    ArrayList<EventAttendee> attendees = new ArrayList<EventAttendee>();
    attendees.add(new EventAttendee().setEmail("xxxxxx@gmail.com"));
    // ...
    event.setAttendees(attendees);

    Date startDate = null;
    Date endDate = null;
    try {
        startDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm").parse(fecha
                + " " + inicio);
        endDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm").parse(fecha
                + " " + fin);

    } catch (ParseException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    DateTime start = new DateTime(startDate, TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires"));
    event.setStart(new EventDateTime().setDateTime(start));
    DateTime end = new DateTime(endDate, TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires"));
    event.setEnd(new EventDateTime().setDateTime(end));

    // lo pongo en el calendario de julia
    try {
        Event createdEvent = service
                .events()
                .insert("xxxxxxxxidfromcalendar@group.calendar.google.com",
                        event).execute();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

Comment: i tried to run your code with my credentials and got: "com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 401 Unauthorized". Do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem recently. For me the solution was to update the library (the sample comes with a bunch of out-dated JARs in the lib/ folder).

My maven dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.23.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-services-plusDomains</artifactId>
        <version>v1-rev449-1.23.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-http-client-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>1.23.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```