# It is possible to get a list of users under a domain with Google + Domains API?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-api, google-plus

I am trying to make some things with the new Google + Domains API, I have been having some troubles, punctually with the java example: https://developers.google.com/+/domains/quickstart/java, here is my question about that: [Google + Domains API Quick start for java is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20382090/google-domains-api-quick-start-for-java-is-not-working),
then I try with  Apps Script, it does not support domain-wide delegation but I think I can make some stuff, my question here is because I would like to get a list of users under my domain, for example, all the users in @example.com, could I make something like this using Google + Domains API? or I am in the wrong way?

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this using the Domains API. The [Google+ Domains API Profiles documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/profiles) has more information about managing user profiles for Google Apps customers and also references the Admin SDK which should also let you get [the list of users on your Domain](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users#get_all_domain_users).

Comment: I have trying with Google + Domains API, if you see my post I mention I can get to work the example with java using domain-wide delegation, inclusive I have posted here in stackoverflow my problem, this is my post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20382090/google-domains-api-quick-start-for-java-is-not-working. I don't know nothing about Admin SDK, I am going to check that, for now I am going to continue working in Apps Script, if you have some idea why I can't get working the java example above cited I would be grateful. Btw, is it possible to use Admin SDK with Apps Script. Thanks

Comment: Would it help if I gave some JavaScript code for accessing the domains API?

Comment: Actually I have tried with admin-sdk in Apps Script and I can get the list of users, right now I don't how to link a field of this information with a field to search in G+ Domains API, I could use email but in Apps Script domain-wide delegation is not supported, I don't know if another field could work. Answering your last question, I think if you have some Javascript working it would be helpful for me, but specially I would like to know if you can make work the example in https://developers.google.com/+/domains/quickstart/java, or you have an idea of my issue, thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: I just got the sample working without needing to make any changes to the sources. I'll follow up on your other question, my first guess is that you are misconfiguring your client.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I am using Admin SDK in Apps Script and it seems to be working, but I am trying to get a full list of user under my domain(domain of my job) and apparently there are too many users, the code is the example in: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/admin-sdk-directory#list_all_users, but the query takes too much time and I get an error saying Exceeded maximum execution time, how can avoid this? can I give more time or reduce the result?

Comment: I still have the problem of having too many users, using Admin SDK in Apps Script I got the error Exceeded maximum execution time, do you have any suggestion?

Comment: @JohnB, go ahead and open a new question tagged to the Google Admin SDK [google-admin-sdk].